# Javascript Library to build drag and drop interface and connect elements with line

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fabricjs, paperjs

I am looking for an approach or Javascript library that I can use to build a scientific modeling application. I suppose this is analogues to the way flowcharting software like Visio works. Add elements and connect them with click and drag.

[image]

I need to be able to define certain elements and add them to the "canvas" by selecting the element and dragging them onto the canvas.

When I click on an element I need to be able to set certain parameters for that element.

I also need to be able to connect one element to another by clicking on one and dragging a line to the second element.

I am looking for some advise on the best javascript library or approach to use. I will probably build the app in Vue.js as I have some experience using it.

Comment: this can be useful: https://github.com/retejs/rete

Comment: @Serg, does the rete library support custom (user-defined) shapes and undo/redo?

Comment: @Nikolay I think it's unsupported. When I looked at the library, the lack of customization was the reason why I gave it up. The main point was that the coordinates initially must be given for all shapes, and that was not suitable for my use case. In the end I switched to Vis.js networks

Answer (score 1):

Given a bit more complicated feature set, I've opted for `mxgraph` (the draw.io library). It's old, it's heavy, it's complicated, it's written in vanilla javascript, and to make it work with Vue you'll probably need to write the integration yourself. But it works, and there is light at the end of the tunnel.

Most important parts for me were: custom complex shape support (like, with groups, and "handles" - you know, these yellow dots you use to "adjust" some shape pieces in Visio for example), undo/redo, save/load, print.

`joint.js` ("rappid" now) may be my second bet if mxgraph won't cut it (not sure how it compares, but the feature list includes the items I needed)

There is also always an option to do it all with plain javascript; you have basic libraries like svg.js, snap.svg, etc that would allow that. moving shapes with drag-drop is no problem even with plain javascript.  But in this case connector routing and undo/redo would be on you, and that's a bit harder.

If you find something better than these options please let me know!

btw, Visio Online does not support custom shapes at all now.